# Media Streaming Servers for Django

Tags: django, live-streaming, django-channels, janus, node-media-server

I and my team are starting a project where in we are building a scalable live streaming platform just like Youtube. We are using Django as the backend framework.
**Which is the best media streaming library/server that can be used to achieve the result(It should work along the django project)?**

Previous Attempts :
We researched about various media streaming servers and shortlisted the following three(based on our requirements that it should be able to scale up to a commercial level):

1. Ngnix RTMP module https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/
2. Node Media Server https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server
3. django channels + Janus webrtc   [https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

We are struggling to decide which one to use for our project. I have seen a lot of people use django channels + Janus webrtc with django to deal with such projects. But one of my teammates had a bad experience with django channels while working on a similar project hence he is advising us not to go with it. Ngnix module is attractive and a really good reputation on github but I didn't understand it well. We are very doubtful of Node Media server, no positive reviews nor negative reviews.
Can you please suggest a better option maybe among them or a different one?
Thank you! Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What are your latency requirements?  What sort of scale are you realistically looking at?